# postgres: why isn't this query using the GIN index on the array value?

Tags: postgresql

SQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE objs (obj_id integer);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sets (obj_id integer[], somecount smallint);

INSERT INTO objs SELECT generate_series(0,10000);
INSERT INTO sets
    SELECT ARRAY[p1.obj_id, p2.obj_id,p3.obj_id], generate_series(0,100)
    FROM objs as p1
    CROSS JOIN objs AS p2
    CROSS JOIN objs AS p3
    WHERE p2.obj_id = p1.obj_id + 1 AND p3.obj_id = p2.obj_id + 1;

CREATE INDEX ON sets USING GIN(obj_id);
SET enable_seqscan = off;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM sets WHERE obj_id @> ARRAY[1,2]::integer[];
```

Yields:

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on sets  (cost=10000000000.00..10000021039.74 rows=25 width=34) (actual time=0.037..333.496 rows=202 loops=1)
   Filter: (obj_id @> '{1,2}'::integer[])
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1009697
 Planning time: 0.727 ms
 Execution time: 333.529 ms
(5 rows)
```

Why is this doing a sequence scan and not using the index?

**UPDATE**

Running this on one DB on my server uses the bitmap heap scan on the index (great!) and running it another does not (boo!) and I don't know why. Same server, different databases.

Comment: The postgres engine may be making a different decision based on the data.  Is the execution time of the sequence scan significantly slower?
Also, is it necessary to use an integer array? Why not have an additional table? Postgres is built to deal with tables and foreign keys moreso than arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postgres extension `intarray` was installed in the database that used the sequential scan, it was clobbering the `@>` operator. Three options:

1. changing the call to `OPERATOR(pg_catalog.@>)` uses in the GIN index.
2. Create the index using the `gin__int_ops` option: `CREATE INDEX ON sets USING GIN(obj_id gin__int_ops);`
3. remove the `intarray` extension (but I require it elsewhere, so nope)